# dblclick event in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon, dom-events, double-click

I'm using the following code in firefox extension, that should alert when double click event occur, but when I double click nothing happens.

```
var Test = {
x: function(e) {
  alert(e.target.defaultView.location.href);
}

}

window.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) { Test.x(); }. false);
```

Comment: -1 for posting your code here instead of checking Error Console - a typo is something that you should be perfectly capable of resolving yourself.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant There was a typo but there is still something wrong. I'd like to show some information from the web page on the event, when I alert("hello") it works but the code above does not work.

Comment: That's one more case where you should have checked Error Console first - it probably says "e.target.defaultView is undefined". Because `e.target` isn't the document, it's the element you clicked. In other words, it should be `e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView`. **Edit**: Oh well, and what @Shef said as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the dot to a comma before the last parameter:

```
window.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) { Test.x(); }, false);
//                                                          .^.
//                                                           | here...
```

#### Update

Your closure also expects a parameter `e` to be passed to it:

```
window.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) { Test.x(e); }, false);
```

Comment: @Shef The typo was not the only one problem.

Comment: @Shef I tried the update but there was no difference in result.

Comment: @Shef There were three errors in total. The third is that Wladimir Palant advised me in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Error Console. It looks like you have syntax errors.

```
var Test = {
x: function(e) {
  alert(e.target.defaultView.location.href);
}

};
```

Added missing semi-colon at the end of the `var` statement. @shef is right about the comma as well.

Comment: JS is a "forgetting" language about the semicolons, that's why it works. However, it is not a good practice to avoid semicolons and it should not be practiced.

Comment: missing semicolon behind namespace was OK.